# Angular mat-list mat-list-item array

Tags: arrays, angular

In my angular code, I am getting a collection of arrays. When I am binding to the angular html code, I am binding column by column with mat-list and mat-list-item. My grid column for example is by names. So my grid will look something like this

John     Joe    Mary    Kim     Steve
Smith    Coe    Downs   Carn    Yeh

#### How can I get the 1st name for the first column and the next name in the array for the next column?

In my collection from the ts, it will look like

```
data = [
  {
    firstname: ['John', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'Kim' 'Steve'],
    lastname: ['Smith', 'Coe', 'Downs', 'Carn' 'Yeh']
  }
];
```

In my html code, I would get the firstname for the first column

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
    {{name.firstname}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list> 
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
    {{name.firstname}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list> 
</div>
```

I only want to get the first name for the 1st column and get the 2nd name in the next column.

My error is that my first column gets all the names in the array.

Thanks

I google the mat-item-list but the examples did not give any clues to what I am trying to  do.

My grid column for example is by names. So my grid will look something like this

John     Joe    Mary    Kim     Steve
Smith    Coe    Downs   Carn    Yeh
In my collection from the ts, it will look like

```
data = [
  { firstname: ['John', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'Kim' 'Steve'],
    lastname: ['Smith', 'Coe', 'Downs', 'Carn' 'Yeh']
  }
]
```

in my html code, I would get the firstname for the first column

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
    {{name.firstname}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list> 
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
    {{name.firstname}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need something like this right? || John | Joe || Mary | Kim || Steve | Smith || Coe | Downs || Carn | Yeh || it uses not only the firstname, you'r output use both firname and last name

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out

```html
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
        {{name.firstname[0]}}
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list> 
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of data">
        {{name.firstname[1]}}
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list> 
    </div>
```